# Google Maps API Key restriction on iOS Apps and Geocoding

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to put restrictions on Google Maps API Key used for both Google Maps SDK on iOS and Geocoding.

Choice 1: Use one API Key.

However, when I restrict an API Key in the following combination, it does not work:

- Application Restriction: iOS Apps
- API Restriction: Geocoding API

Alternative workaround I found, create two API Keys:

- API Key 1: Maps SDK for iOS; Application Restriction: iOS Apps
- API Key 2: Geocoding API;  API restriction: Geocoding API

The problem with the alternative solution is, my API Key 2 remains vulnerable since there is no Application Restriction in place.

Comment: Geocoding API is a web service and it supports only IP address restrictions as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem. You should mount an intermediate server in order to protect your API key for Geocoding. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736854/can-i-restrict-google-direction-api-to-ios-apps-only/40744769#40744769

Comment: Geocoding API is a web service and it supports only IP address restrictions as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem. You should mount an intermediate server in order to protect your API key for Geocoding. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736854/can-i-restrict-google-direction-api-to-ios-apps-only/40744769#40744769