# How can I restrict unauthorized access of Google Directions Api Http request on ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-directions-api

I have integrated **Google Directions Api** in one of my **IOS** application.

I am making **Http** request to this Api for drawing route between two point on map:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/..........
```

My main concern is to secure my Api request, so that only my specific IOS application can access it?

I have tried applying **bundle id** restriction on Google api using **Google Cloud Platform**, If I am not wrong, as Google Directions Api is a webservice and Google is unable to identify that bundle and Google only identifies requests from **IOS SDK Libraries**.

Is there any way to restrict Google Directions Api?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736854/can-i-restrict-google-direction-api-to-ios-apps-only

check this it will help you.

Comment: @junaid this thread is not helpful. This thread is ask from server side api request. It means i have to ping a server and that server will ping google and then i will get response

Comment: Google direction key also take api key parameter

check this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: You can restrict it using api key

Comment: @junaid Do you mean this: &key=YOUR_API_KEY
???

Comment: Yes i am talking about this key.

Comment: I already have provided the key, my concern is to restrict and secure that api key

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#key-restrictions

Check api restriction doc

Comment: I have read that already. This article push me to implement the server side logic.. which requires 2 http requests for getting data from google

Comment: i think api keys are restricted to particular app